# How to set QTextEdit formatting to preserve quote indentation, superscripts, and subscripts?

Tags: qt, markdown, qtextedit

I'm working on making an application that has a rich text editor that saves in Markdown format. As Markdown obviously isn't capable of displaying many rich text features, I'm limiting the formatting features I expose to only just those that are compatible with GitHub Flavored Markdown (the default Markdown format supported by QTextEdit, and one which has a couple nice features I'd like).

The problem I'm having is that not all of the formatting that ought to be compatible with GFM is getting preserved. Bold, italic, and strikethrough all seem to be preserved when I use `QTextEdit::toMarkdown()`, but quote blocks (which are an essential feature for me) are *not* preserved for some reason.

Currently the way I'm indenting a block of text is to use code similar to this:

```
void MainWindow::applyBlockFormat(QTextBlockFormat format)
{
    ui->documentTextEdit->textCursor().setBlockFormat(format);
}

...

QTextBlockFormat format;
format.setIndent(1);
applyBlockFormat(format);
```

(for clarity, `ui` is my application's main window object, while `documentTextEdit` is a QTextEdit object.)

This works perfectly fine in the rich text editor, but when I actually save the document (using `QTextEdit::toMarkdown()` to get a QString with the document's contents), I can open the saved file and see that all indented text is *not* prefixed with a `>` marker like I would expect. It seems to be treated exactly as if it weren't indented.

At this point I tried to debug by writing a Markdown file by hand with a quote block, then loading it using `QTextEdit::setMarkdown()`. The quote block rendered as I expected (indented), however after inspecting things with some `qDebug()` statements I saw that the block's left margin was set to 40 rather than its indent being set to 1. So I went and changed my code so that it used `format.setLeftMargin(40)` instead of `format.setIndent(1)`, then tried writing a file with indented text in it again. The saved file *still* did not end up with a quote block marker (`>`).

Finally, the last odd thing. If I load a file that has block quotes, modify it, save it, and then open the resulting file in a text editor, I can see that file *does* have quote blocks in it. I can even type a newline followed by some text in an indented block, and it will make a new indented line (complete with quote block marker).

What setting am I missing here? I've tried setting the `Qt::BlockQuoteLevel` property on the `format` object to `1`, to no avail.

I'm using Qt 5.15.3 on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Remember that rich text content **always** uses the QTextDocument structure. Functions like `setHtml()`/`toHtml()` or `setMarkDown()`/`toMarkDown()` are helper functions that parse and convert the input into a QTextDocument or convert that to the requested format, respectively. I've not dug into markdown behavior yet, but I'd suggest you to do some debug tests to show the actual QTextFormats (and related) used for each frame/block. Also note that there are *two* indent properties (`TextIndent` and `BlockIndent`) and that the format indent is multiplied by the document's `indentWidth`.

Comment: @musicamante Didn't know about the two different indents, I'll check that out.